# Work with binary numbers as scalars in Matlab

Tags: matlab, hdl, hdl-coder

I am working with a MATLAB function that uses numbers in the binary base. To do so it uses the function `dec2bin` to transform an integer into a char array containing the binary information. The issue is that I plan to use HDL Coder to generate a HDL version of the function. One step of the process is to convert the variables to fixed point. This can be done automatically when the data is a scalar, so is there any way to manage binary numbers without using vectors?

Comment: Sure. Store the binary values in an integer type of the proper size. Then they will be scalars.

Answer (score 1):

`dec2bin` is just for display purposes. Numbers are always stored in the computer using binary representation. You can use the functions
[`bitand`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitand.html),
[`bitor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitor.html),
[`bitxor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitxor.html),
[`bitcmp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitcmp.html),
[`bitshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitshift.html),
[`bitget`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitget.html), and 
[`bitset`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitset.html)
to do bit-wise manipulation of integer numbers:

```
>> a = uint32(7);
>> b = uint32(12);
>> bitand(a, b)
ans =
  uint32
   4
```

(Click on the function names above for the documentation. You can also do `help bitand` in MATLAB to read a shorter version of the documentation or `doc bitand` to read the full documentation.)